# Can I use tcpdump to measure end to end latency (including kernel times)?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, tcpdump

On a Ubuntu 14.04 server I am trying to measure the end to end time my software stack takes to process a UDP packet and emit a corresponding TCP response. I am looking for microsecond level precision at least.

My strategy was to capture network traffic on the machine with tcpdump and then analyze the traffic to pair UDP and TCP packets and produce same statics using their relative timestamps. This seems to work OK, in that the timings I obtained are consistent with those that I get with application level tracing.

However, I am left wondering if I am actually capturing most of the time spent in the Linux kernel processing UDP and TCP (which is my intention) or if perhaps tcpdump timestamps the packets too early or too late for this measurement to be useful ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, tcpdump supports hardware timestamping. If you turn on HW timestamping and your NIC and driver supports it, you can get microsecond precision. On e.g. the Intel i210 (good, nonexpensive gigabit/s NIC) the send timestamp is taken right before the MAC puts the packet to the PHY, and the delay MAC->PHY is well-known and compensated for by the driver.

If you want to measure time from userspace to PHY, there are ways of correlating NIC clock and system clock, and compare timestamps taken in userspace with the HW timestamps. If you do so, you may have to compensate for clock drift. For example, the clock drift on the i210 is up to 30ppm if I recall correctly, and it can increase with age of the clock crystal, in addition to temperature variations.

For more info, see e.g. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt

I also have made some test programs, see https://github.com/alapaa/timestamping/tree/send_queue

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful response. I have learned a great deal from it. I have not closed the question because I still would like to know how representative of the total kernel time the software time stamping is (the particular card I am working with does not support HW time stamping). I will update the question if I find this out elsewhere.

Comment: OK. Concerning kernel processing time, and also user-space processing time: In a setup with two fast Xeon machines connected over a gigabit switch, the time spent in kernel and userspace on the receiver machine is usually most (maybe 70%) of total round-trip-time (RTT). So for short RTT, the actual time spent in the network is lower than the time spent in software 'turning the packet around'.

Comment: Is the timestamp of received packets taken right after the MAC gets the packet from the PHY?

Comment: It has been 4 years since I worked on this, so I suggest you check kernel docs or the code.

Comment: @falkb If I remember correctly, some of the NICs even compensate for the time from PHY to NIC, so the timestamp is when the packet arrives at the PHY.